# Escaping character in JS while appending HTML in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a `HTML` Canvas in which I  want to append couple of html canvas.

```
 <div>
        <canvas id="BackGroundImage" width="800" height="300"
    style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="300"
    style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1;"></canvas>
        </div> '
```

Like this.

```
append(''<div>\
            <canvas id="BackGroundImage" width="800" height="300"\
        style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;"></canvas>\
            <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="300"\
        style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1;"></canvas\>
            </div>'');
```

But this doesnt work the sapces after canvas give me error saying `unterminated statements`.

Comment: Since ES2015 you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get multi-line strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

issue 1:  append(' ' // string is not properly created.

issue 2 : `</canvas\>`

```js
$("body").append('<div> I am added, inspect me in dev console and found the desired html\
            <canvas id="BackGroundImage" width="800" height="300"\
        style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;"></canvas>\
            <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="300"\
        style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1;"></canvas>\
            </div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
append('<div>'+
            '<canvas id="BackGroundImage" width="800" height="300"'+
        'style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;"></canvas>'+
            '<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="300"'+
        'style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1;"></canvas\>'+
            '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
append('<div>'+
'<canvas id="BackGroundImage" width="800" height="300"'+
' style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;"></canvas>'+
'<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="300"'
+' style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1;"></canvas\> </div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, but the problem is you used `/` instead of `+`, some other people make problems by adding `'` inside `''` or `"` inside `""`

```js
$('.here').append('<div>' +
  '<canvas id="BackGroundImage" width="800" height="300"' +
  'style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;"></canvas>' +
  '<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="300"' +
  'style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1;"></canvas\>' +
  '</div>'+
'<h1>Added</h1>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="here">
  
  </div>
```